# Image upload via gridview question

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview, file-upload

I have a gridview that displays data from a database.  The datbase stores the image filename (string) among other things for an item.

I have the fileupload control showing in the EDIT view, and that uploads the file just fine.

The problem is, I want to update the image filename in the database and I am not sure how to get the data to the textbox control that the gridview uses to UPDATE the database.  The textbox control i have set the visibility to hidden.  here is the aspx code:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="Image">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtImage" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Image") %>' Visible="False" OnTextChanged="txtImage_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>                        
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="50px" AlternateText='<%# Eval("Image") %>' ImageUrl='<%# "images/hardware/" + Eval("Image") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

And here is the function that stores the file onto the server, and places the filename into a variable:

```
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        FileUpload fileUpload = row.Cells[0].FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload;
         if ( fileUpload != null && fileUpload.HasFile)
         {
             strFileName = fileUpload.FileName;
             fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/hardware/" + strFileName));
             TextBox txtImage = row.Cells[0].FindControl("txtImage") as TextBox;
             txtImage.Text = strFileName;
         }
    }
```

So where do I go from here?  I think the update has occured already or something?  Because the "txtImage.Text" does not update the database...  Am I out of order here or something?  I can manipulate values in the textbox in this function before it gets saved to the DB right?  Thanks for your help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you handle updating the database in the code behind you should be able to get the file name like you did in GridView1_RowUpdating. Just find the row in the grid that is in edit mode. Each row in the rows collection on the grid has a RowState property...your looking for DataControlRowState.Edit

Comment: Not really updating in the code behind I don't think... I am using the "UpdateQuery" property of the dataset to handle the update.

Comment: Your answer below looks good, when you are not able to two way bind elements adding their values to the update collection by hooking a data source event is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution, but would like input into whether this is a good way of coding it.
I have this setup as the "Updating" event for the dataset the gridview uses:

```
        protected void SetRecords(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (strFileName != "")
        {
            e.Command.Parameters["@Image"].Value = strFileName;
        }
    }
```

Is this ok?  Everything seems to work just fine... but is this a good way to solve the problem?  I would like to code properly and not start bad coding practices right from the start (I am an accomplished classic ASP developer moving to C# and ASP.NET)
Thanks all!